# communicate with peripherals in PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, device-driver

We are going to develop a cross platform app using PWA and wonder if we can communicate to device drivers like thermal printer specific drivers or bluetooth devices which all of them have their own device drivers.

We don't need to use bluetooth or working with ports directly.

I know that inter-application communication is not yet supported in PWA ( https://whatwebcando.today/ ) but want to know is there any other solution that may help us to have this done.

I read about webshare too but unfortunately it's about text not anything like images to print.

Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.